# toggle dynamic data in footable using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, footable

How to toggle dynamic data using footable and knockout?

The objective is to load each record's available children on toggle:

```
Example list of records:
ParentName1
     Child1 : description
     Child2 : description
ParentName2
     Child1 : description
ParentName3
     Child1 : description
     Child2 : description
     Child3 : description
```

Each record can have possible multiple children.

I was able to bind the records (parent) using knockout and footable v2 as plug-in.

I'm having difficulty on loading the children for each record and display it with footable.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We love to answer well-posed programming questions. Have a look at ["how to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider editing your post to add more details (such as code you have tried so far) so it will attract answers.

Comment: What did you try? what difficulty are you facing?

Comment: @goto, I've tried using jquery syntax to append the data but no luck...$('table thead th:last-child').after('<th>test</th>');

Comment: Does anyone has a clever solution?...Many thanks!!